# Android google maps api v2 - Google play services missing

Tags: android, google-maps, exception

> **Device** - HTC Wildfire 
>   **Android OS version** - 2.3.3

I am trying to run google maps api v2 examples on the phone.

These are the Logcat messages -

```
03-08 12:43:34.687: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5517): Google Play services is missing.
03-08 12:43:34.687: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5517): Google Play services is missing.
03-08 12:43:34.687: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5517): Google Play services is missing.
03-08 12:43:34.697: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5517): Google Play services is missing.
```

And on the application i am getting a button that says - **get google play services**. 
When I click on the button i am getting an exception . The Logcat says -

```
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1569)
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1539)
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2974)
03-08 12:43:36.847: E/AndroidRuntime(5517):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
```

Based on the above messages i came to know that google play services are missing on my phone . 
My Phone has Market application (Not the google play).

**Few Questions** -

1. How can i update the **Market** to **google play store**?
2. Is there a way through which i can install google play services? (Note: The Google Play services APK is not visible by searching the Google Play Store. The client library provides a deep link into the Google Play Store when it detects that the device has a missing or incompatible Google Play services APK. )

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have You installed Google Play Services using SDK Manager? It's in the "Extras" folder.

Comment: @RodionAltshuler : No i have not installed it. Can you please let me know the steps of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Run "SDK Manager.exe" file that is located in your Android SDK folder. 2. Find "Google play services" in the list (see closer to the bottom, "Extras" folder), choose and click "Install packages".

Comment: Oh.. Yes i have done it already. The issue is device specific. I dont have google play store installed on my device. The app runs fine on devices which have play store / google play service installed on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the

> Settings -> Software updates -> Check now

My Phone downloaded and installed some updates.
This time when i clicked on

> Get Google Play Services (In the application )

**Market** automatically got updated to **Google Play**.

Map is getting displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing an application that uses Google Maps API and requires your customers' phones to have it, be sure to handle the case that you find yourself in now. Many Gingerbread phones don't ship with Google Play Services, and the error message that is displayed by default has the wrong link in it. This is a known bug, which has a discussion on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543). You should check for installation on app startup, and safely send the user to the right place to download if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got a HTC Evo 4G (the 2010 IO conference giveaway for Sprint U.S deployed Wimax networks)
and while I never used it in a real Wimax network (not deployed in Sweden) it can otherwise come handy as a 2.3.3 test phone.

It updated to 2.3.3 the other day when I picked it up out of a forgotten drawer. The Market app that should automagically be replaced by the Google Play app still remains. I need Play so that the Google Maps v2 dependencies shipped inside Google Play come available to my app that use Google Maps v2. I read clearing the Market app cache would be good, but no difference.

Any hints ?